# how can I update/moving my canvasjs chart without refreshing page in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, canvasjs

Here is my whole code of PHP and Canvasjs chart code. Actually, I'm done creating the chart and it is successfully shown, thus I want to make it moving without refreshing the page because the data from the database is constantly. When I refresh the page then all lines of the chart shown with the latest data from the database but I want how my chart moving without refreshing and fetching the latest data from the database and will show on the chart. **here is my dataset**:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [x] => 1614591919000 [y] => 0 ) ).

```js
<script>
function fun2() {
 
var updateInterval = <?php echo $updateInterval ?>;
var dataPoints1 = <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
var dataPoints2 = <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints2, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
var dataPoints3 = <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints3, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
var dataPoints4 = <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints4, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
var yValue1 = <?php echo $GT1 ?>;
var yValue2 = <?php echo $GT2 ?>;
var yValue3 = <?php echo $ST ?>;
var yValue4 = <?php echo $TL ?>;
var xValue = <?php echo $x ?>;
 
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2", {
    zoomEnabled: true,
    title: {
        text: "Trend Graph of Balloki"
    },
    // axisX: {
    //  title: "chart updates every " + updateInterval / 1000 + " secs"
    // },
    axisY:{
        suffix: " watts"
    }, 
    toolTip: {
        shared: true
    },
    legend: {
        cursor:"pointer",
        verticalAlign: "top",
        fontSize: 22,
        fontColor: "dimGrey",
        itemclick : toggleDataSeries
    },
    data: [{ 
            type: "line",
            name: "GT1",
            xValueType: "dateTime",
            yValueFormatString: "#,### watts",
            xValueFormatString: "hh:mm:ss TT",
            showInLegend: true,
            legendText: "{name} " + yValue1 + " watts",
            dataPoints: dataPoints1
        },
        {               
            type: "line",
            name: "GT2" ,
            xValueType: "dateTime",
            yValueFormatString: "#,### watts",
            showInLegend: true,
            legendText: "{name} " + yValue2 + " watts",
            dataPoints: dataPoints2
        },
        {               
            type: "line",
            name: "ST" ,
            xValueType: "dateTime",
            yValueFormatString: "#,### watts",
            showInLegend: true,
            legendText: "{name} " + yValue3 + " watts",
            dataPoints: dataPoints3
        },
        {               
            type: "line",
            name: "TL" ,
            xValueType: "dateTime",
            yValueFormatString: "#,### watts",
            showInLegend: true,
            legendText: "{name} " + yValue4 + " watts",
            dataPoints: dataPoints4
        }
    ]
});
 
chart.render();
setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval);
 
function toggleDataSeries(e) {
    if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
        e.dataSeries.visible = false;
    }
    else {
        e.dataSeries.visible = true;
    }
    chart.render();
}
 
function updateChart() {
    var deltaY1, deltaY2, deltaY3, deltaY4;
    xValue += updateInterval;
    // adding random value
    yValue1 += Math.round(2 + Math.random() *(-2-2));
    yValue2 += Math.round(2 + Math.random() *(-2-2));
    yValue3 += Math.round(2 + Math.random() *(-2-2));
    yValue4 += Math.round(2 + Math.random() *(-2-2));
 
    // pushing the new values
    dataPoints1.push({
        x: xValue,
        y: yValue1
    });
    dataPoints2.push({
        x: xValue,
        y: yValue2
    });
    dataPoints3.push({
        x: xValue,
        y: yValue3
    });
    dataPoints4.push({
        x: xValue,
        y: yValue4
    });
 
    // updating legend text with  updated with y Value 
    chart.options.data[0].legendText = "GT1 " + yValue1 + " Mega watts";
    chart.options.data[1].legendText = " GT2 " + yValue2+ " Mega watts"; 
    chart.options.data[3].legendText = "ST " + yValue3 + "  Mega watts";
    chart.options.data[4].legendText = " TL " + yValue4+ " Mega watts"; 
    chart.render();
}
 
}
window.onload = function() {
   
    fun2();
}
</script>
```

```html
<?php
$db =mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","trend");
$dataPoints1 = array();
$dataPoints2 = array();
$dataPoints3 = array();
$dataPoints4 = array();
$updateInterval = 2000; //in millisecond
$initialNumberOfDataPoints = 200;
$x = time() * 1000 - $updateInterval * $initialNumberOfDataPoints;
    $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `pload` WHERE DT > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)"); //WHERE DT > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $GT1 = $row['GT1'];
        $GT2 = $row['GT2']; 
        $ST = $row['ST'];
        $TL = $row['TL'];   
        array_push($dataPoints1, array("x" => $x, "y" => $GT1));
        array_push($dataPoints2, array("x" => $x, "y" => $GT2));
        array_push($dataPoints3, array("x" => $x, "y" => $ST));
        array_push($dataPoints4, array("x" => $x, "y" => $TL));
        $x += $updateInterval;
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried using ajax to request to new data?

Comment: Or [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), to avoid unnecessarily using jQuery. Also if I may suggest to OP: When wrapping you PHP code in triple backticks (```), you may add `php` right after the opening triple backtics, to ensure proper syntax highlighting.

Comment: @PaulDigz yes sir I tried but fruitless

Comment: @ahmad What I was thinking is that maybe you can use ajax to get the data then reinitialize the chart using new data.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [@PaulDigz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13932995/paul-digz) you can perform AJAX to the data and update datapoints by [changing chart.options and call chart.render()](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/updating-chart-options/). Refer this [discussion thread](https://canvasjs.com/forums/topic/how-can-i-use-php-mysql-dynamic-data/) for more info / working code. You can also checkout this [demo project](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Al_ZS_39Ng7thTIRR_MmSy_O573v) for a working sample on the same.